# Сгенерировать.создать ER Diagrams сл связями в Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Сделала все по инструкции из видео (открыла DB Diagram---Create New Diagram  и перетощила все таблицы в появившееся окно, ) но связи так и не появились. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Связей действительно не было, вопрос отпал.